# c++ stl map iterators outputting values a hex

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

I have the following code:

```
map<StatTypesEnum, ValueHandler*>::const_iterator itr;

for(itr=player1->Stats.begin(); itr!=player1->Stats.end(); itr++)
{
    cout << "Stat: " << itr->first << " Value: " << (ValueHandler*)(itr->second)->getValue() << endl;
}
```

The getValue() method returns an int.  If I cout the value outside of the iterator, it displays in base10 decimal, however when i return the value using an iterator (as above) it displays in base16, hex.

Just for completeness, the following line displays as base10:

```
cout << player1->Stats[Power]->getValue() << endl;
```

I would like the iterator to display base10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you print `(ValueHandler*)(itr->second)->getValue()` you should be getting a hexadecimal value because that's how pointers are printed. You probably shouldn't be casting the return value of `getValue()` to a `ValueHandler*`. You probably intended to cast `itr->second` to that pointer type (although it's not necessary) but just got the parentheses wrong. Here's what casting `itr->second` would look like:

```
((ValueHandler*) itr->second)->getValue()
```

And what you want is probably:

```
itr->second->getValue()
```

Comment: Yes - much simpler - for some reason I thought I would need to cast itr->second but it is already the right type. - thanks

Answer (score 1):

`(ValueHandler*)(itr->second)->getValue()` is a pointer, not an `int`. You're casting the return value of `getValue`.

Maybe you want `((ValueHandler*)(itr->second))->getValue()`? Which is redundant anyway.

Comment: You don't need to cast this one at all, the iterator knows which type it is.